# In this code, Why am I getting wrong output only for input value of 4.2 while it is working well for other values?

Tags: c

The following code converts dollars (floating values) into cents (integer values). Here 1 dollar == 100 cents. The code works flawlessly except for one value i.e 4.2. It gives output as 419 instead of 420 for 4.2 as input. Where is the bug?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{   
    float change;

    do
    {
        printf("O hai! Enter amount in dollars to convert in cents.\n");

        scanf("%f",&change);   //accepts input in dollars

    } while(change < 0.00);

    int i = change * 100;    //converts dollars into cents

    printf("The equivalent cents are %d\n",i);
}
```

Comment: Time to read the [floating point guide](http://floating-point-gui.de).

Comment: And [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) It is best to use `int` types for "change" problems and work in cents.

Comment: Always prefer `double` when dealing with floating point values.

Comment: have you checked all possible float values and make sure that this is the only one that's not working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Not all possible float values but I tried several similar combinations like 3.1, 5.1, 4.15 and so on for which that code worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this behavior because of the way a `float` is represented.

In [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), `4.2` is actually stored as `4.19999980926513671875` so that when you multiply it by `100` and cast it back to an `int`, you get `419` (*i.e.* the integer part of the result).

A solution would be to use

```
int i = (int) roundf(change * 100);
```

or

```
int i = (int) lrintf(change * 100);
```

with `#include <math.h>`.

Comment: Consider `long int lrintf(float x)` which rounds and converts to an integer type in one call.

Comment: @chux Thanks. For readability, I still prefer an explicit type casting (although lighter than from `double`), though.

Answer (score 2):

Many floating point values do not have an exact representation in base 2.

You can try adding a very small value to push the value a little bit:

```
int i = (change + 0.0001) * 100;    //converts dollars into cents
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see [here](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) when you store a value in a `float` the actual number stored is not always what you expected. This is due to how floats are represented in binary (you can learn more on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic)).

Now, as shown in the [1st link](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html), when you try to store `4.2` in change, you actually store `4.19...`. Multiply it by 100, store it inside an `int`,and you get 419.

Changing your `float` into `double` will give you better (*double*) precision, and in your case, it will yield the expected result

```
double change; # float changed to double
do
{
    printf("O hai! Enter amount in dollars to convert in cents.\n");

    scanf("%lf",&change);   //accepts input in dollars # "%f" changed to "%lf"

} while(change < 0.00);

int i = change * 100;    //converts dollars into cents

printf("The equivalent cents are %d\n",i);

input: 4.2
output: 420
```

on my machine.

Note that using `double` is not a fail-safe. It can also give misleading results, but it should behave better than `float`.

Comment: The extra precision of `double` vs `float` does not help, in general.  Converting `x.9999999` or `x.99999999999999999` to an `int` is just as problematic.

Comment: As I mentioned, double is a better, not overall good. For this post, is makes the difference :)

Comment: For the value of 4.2 using `double` may make a difference, but it does not decrease the chance of the problem versus using `float`.  About half of all "decimal" values like 4.2, 1.23, 123.456, ... have this problem using `float` _or_ `double`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case that you know that the decimals for work with money are 2, I suggest that work with float representation with 3 decimals, and then the result must do round up to 2 decimals. Is important be carefully, because the working with money is very delicate.
Hope this help.